# name = "this or that" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("input[name=foo]:checked,input[name=bar]:checked")
```

but I would like to make it smaller with something like:

```
$("input[name=foo|bar]:checked")
```

Is there anything like that?

Comment: What about giving them both a class, i.e. `foobar` and then use `$("input.foobar:checked")`

Comment: You shouldn't worry making that kind of things smaller. Worry about other things in your code.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Luca. Especially that in some situations making things smaller may cause the selector to be slightly slower.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest version, as inputs are the only things that "should" have names.

```
$('[name=foo],[name=bar]');
```

A bit more safe as inputs are the only things that can actually be checked.

```
$(":checked").filter('[name=foo],[name=bar]');
```

Exactly as safe as your original selector, but two characters shorter:

```
$("input:checked").filter('[name=foo],[name=bar]');
```

But generally I agree, there is no real need and you're better off spending your time elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that, you can use James Padolsey's [regex selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/):

```
$("input:regex(name,^(foo|bar)$):checked")
```

But that's less clear than your original code in my opinion.